# How to apply Zorn's Lemma to prove cardinalities are a total order?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, axiom-of-choice, transfinite-induction

I'm currently self studying Analysis I by Tao. He's sprinkled a little set theory into this book, and I'm really struggling to apply it. After painstakingly proving Zorn's Lemma via another lemma, we are given this very much non-obvious exercise:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty sets such that $A$ does not have lesser or equal cardinality to $B$. Using the principle of transfinite indcuction, prove that $B$ has lesser or equal cardinality to $A$. (Hint: for every subset $X \subseteq B$, let $P(X)$ denote the property that there exists an injective map from $X$ to $A$. This exercise (combined with Exercise 8.3.3 [Schroeder-Bernstein]) shows that cardinality of any two sets is comparable, as long as one assumes the axiom of choice.

His definition of transfinite induction is as follows:

> We give some applications of Zorn's lemma (also called the *principle of transfinite induction*) in the exercises below.

That's it. I feel like I've been thrown not even into the deep end, but pretty much into the ocean. How could I even begin to solve that using Zorn's lemma? I don't see any partial order that could in any way be useful to solve this, and I don't see any way to maximise. Am I missing something obvious, or is this just really hard?

Comment: Most, if not all the links here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/421638

Answer (score 0):

Without wanting to give too much away, here's an idea of how you might use Zorn's Lemma in general:

- Pick a partial order Q that's relevant for your problem
- Show it's nonempty
- Show that every total order in Q has an upper bound in Q
- You now know Q contains a maximal element: use it to solve your problem

In this case, you're given the hint that you're to consider subsets $X$ of $B$...

Other vague hints: to prove $B$ has lesser or equal cardinality to $A$, you can give an injection from $B$ to $A$.